# Quitar condicionales en Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, formato-condicional

Poseo el siguiente código implementado en Python Flask en el cual como se puede ser, recibo varios datos por el método `POST` y a la vez trato de hacer validaciones (las cuales funcionan correctamente) pero, sinceramente queda muy feo y poco serio tener tantos condicionales con el mismo formato

Aclaro, que en el POST deben venir todas las variables, vacias o no.
Lo que necesito verificar es que no vengan vacias ciertas variables

Existe alguna forma para poder realizar ese tipo de validaciones pero con alguna libreria?

```
@teachers.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def add_teacher():
    ##NECESARIO PARA CARGAR EL PROFESOR, PERO NO TENEMOS AUN EL IDUSER
    nameTeacher = request.json['nameTeacher']
    photoTeacher = request.json['photoTeacher']
    dniTeacher = request.json['dniTeacher']
    cellphoneTeacher = request.json['cellphoneTeacher']
    observationTeacher = request.json['observationTeacher']
    idTdni = request.json['idTdni']
    idCountry = request.json['idCountry']
    idProvince = request.json['idProvince']
    idCountry=request.json['idCountry']
    datebirthTeacher=request.json['datebirthTeacher']
    dateTeacher= datetime.now(tz)
    editTeacher=None

    #Para el post ninguno de los siguientes campos puede venir vacio, si observationTeacher y photoTeacher
    if (nameTeacher=='' or dniTeacher=='' or cellphoneTeacher==''  or idTdni=='' or idCountry=='' or idProvince=='' or idCountry=='' or datebirthTeacher==''):
      return jsonify({"statusCode":200},{"ERROR": "Exist fields null"}),200


    ##NECESARIO PARA CARGAR EL USUARIO
    idTuser = request.json['idTuser']
    nameUser = request.json['nameUser']
    passwordUser=request.json['passwordUser'].encode('utf-8')
    emailUser=request.json['emailUser']
    activeUser=request.json['activeUser']
    dateUser = datetime.now(tz)

    #Validaciones
    checkEmail= validate_email(email_address=emailUser, check_regex=True, check_mx=True)
    if (checkEmail==True):
      emailUser=emailUser
    else:
      return jsonify({"statusCode":200},{"ERROR": "Invalid format or not exist email"}),200

    
    try:
      cellphoneTeacher = int(cellphoneTeacher)
      pass
    except ValueError:
      return jsonify({"statusCode":200},{"ERROR": "Invalid Cellphone"}),200

    if ' ' in nameUser: 
      return jsonify({"statusCode":200},{"ERROR": "Username cannot contain spaces"}),200


    else: 
      pass

    
    
    ##VERIFICO SI EXISTE EL DNI EN EL PAIS EN LA BASE DE DATOS O EL NOMBRE DE USUARIO (PARAMETROS LIMITANTES DE LA CARGA)
    dni_control=Teacher.query.filter_by(dniTeacher=dniTeacher).filter_by(idCountry=idCountry).first()

    ##VERIFICO SI EXISTE EL NOMBRE DE USUARIO (PARAMETROS LIMITANTES DE LA CARGA)
    nameuser_control=User.query.filter_by(nameUser=nameUser).first()

    
    ##SI HAY USUARIO CARGADO CON EL DNI EN EL PAIS 
    if (dni_control != None ):

      return jsonify({"statusCode":200},{"ERROR": "There is already in the Country a teacher with the DNI "+ dni_control.dniTeacher}),200

    ##SI NO HAY USUARIO CARGADO CON EL DNI
    else:
        pass


    ##SI HAY USUARIO CARGADO CON EL NOMBRE DE USUARIO
    if (nameuser_control != None ):
      return jsonify({"statusCode":200},{"ERROR": "There is already a User with the Name "+ nameuser_control.nameUser}),200
          
          ##SI NO HAY USUARIO CARGADO CON EL NOMBRE DE USUARIO
    else:
        pass
    
    #HASHEO DE PASSWORD
    #hashedpassword = bcrypt.hashpw(passwordUser, bcrypt.gensalt(14))
    hasheada = hashlib.md5(passwordUser) 
    hexa = hasheada.hexdigest()
    ##CREO EL USUARIO
    new_user=(User(nameUser,hexa,idTuser,emailUser,activeUser,dateUser))
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

    #OBTENGO EL ID QUE SE CREO, BASANDOME EN EL NOMBRE (TENIENDO EN CUENTA QUE POR EL CONTROL ANTERIOR; EL NOMBRE NO SE REPITE)
    name_user=User.query.filter_by(nameUser=nameUser).first()
    id_user=name_user.idUser

    #CREO TEACHER
    new_teacher= Teacher(nameTeacher,photoTeacher,dniTeacher,cellphoneTeacher,observationTeacher,idTdni,idCountry,
    idProvince,id_user,datebirthTeacher,dateTeacher,editTeacher)
    db.session.add(new_teacher)
    db.session.commit()
    result=teacher_schema.dump(new_teacher)
    if result:
      return jsonify(result,{"statusCode":200},{"ContentType": "application/json"}),200
    else:
      return jsonify(result,{"statusCode":404},{"ERROR": "Modules not found"}),404
```

Answer (score 1):

En verdad no necesitas ninguna librería para ello, puedes simplemente usar un try-except ya que al hacer `nameTeacher = request.json['nameTeacher']` si `nameTeacher` no existe te dará un error:

```
try:
    nameTeacher = request.json['nameTeacher']
    photoTeacher = request.json['photoTeacher']
    dniTeacher = request.json['dniTeacher']
    cellphoneTeacher = request.json['cellphoneTeacher']
    observationTeacher = request.json['observationTeacher']
    idTdni = request.json['idTdni']
    idCountry = request.json['idCountry']
    idProvince = request.json['idProvince']
    idCountry=request.json['idCountry']
    datebirthTeacher=request.json['datebirthTeacher']
except:
    return return jsonify({"statusCode":400},{"ERROR": "Exist fields null"}),400
```

Además, estás devolviendo un 200, que es solicitud OK, si algo ha fallado lo normal sería devolver un código de error 400 indicando qué ha sucedido.

*Edito: Mover comprobaciones a otra función*

Dado que request.json es un diccionario, puedes declarar la siguiente función, que comprueba cada clave del diccionario y en el momento que encuentra una vacía devuelve false, si todas tienen contenido, devolverá true

```
def check_data(data):
    for key in data.keys():
        if data[key] == "":
            return False
    return True
```

Y en tu método haces lo siguiente:

```
@teachers.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def add_teacher():
    if not check_data(request.json):
         return return jsonify({"statusCode":400},{"ERROR": "Exist fields null"}),400

    #Sigue con tu código normal aquí
```

Te quedará mucho más limpio y no necesitas incluir ninguna librería extra

Comment: Claro, el caso es que las variables si o si vienen en el POST, el caso es si viene vacio o no. Me entendes?

Comment: Oh, entiendo. Te recomiendo indicarlo en la pregunta.
De todos modos, una posible solución sería hacer un método para analizar si alguno de ellos está vacío, de esa manera moverías todas las comprobaciones a otra zona del código (preferiblemente a otro archivo "utils" y te quedará el código más limpio, con una simple llamada a la función

Comment: Barabaro, ahora modifico la pregunta, gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Te añadí un ejemplo de cómo podría quedar

Answer (score 0):

Dos pequeñas cosas que pueden hacer que el código sea un poco más limpio. Todas las líneas que dicen

```
else
   pass
```

son redundantes y pueden ser eliminadas (si no se cumple la condición, el programa simplemente seguirá su curso). Del mismo modo, en los casos como `if nameTeacher != None:` se puede simplificar y poner como `if nameTeacher:`, lo que le bastará a Python para comprender que debe tener un valor.